# Split file on the value of a certain column into separate files and also include the header

Tags: bash, csv, awk

fullfile.csv:

```
animal,number
rabbit,1
fish,2
mouse,1
dog,1
lizard,2
cat,2
```

And I want to split the file on the value in the second column,
and used this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","}; {print > ("file"$2".csv")}' fullfile.csv
```

Outputs:

file1.csv

```
rabbit,1
mouse,1
dog,1
```

file2.csv

```
fish,2
lizard,2
cat,2
```

However there is no header in file1.csv or file2.csv so I tried to add it like so:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","}; NR==1 { print } {print > ("file"$2".csv")}' fullfile.csv
```

But the header prints to the command line instead of going to each file. How do I get the header to be included in each file?

Comment: My personal preference would be not to use awk for the first line, and simply start with a `head -1` for both files. But I am pretty sure you can do it with awk if you'd introduce an `if` and print to both files using two print statements. However, it would need some creativity if the number of files isn't fixed and determined by the contents of the file's second column... Then it would probably be easier to write a perl or bash script for it...

Comment: Thanks for the input.. it doesn't have to be in awk.. I've thought about using the awk line and then adding the first header to each file using sed: sed -i -e 'header line' file.csv... but that requires copying and pasting the header line and substituting it in the script every time I need to run this... hoping there was an easier, less error-prone way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also specify the field separator outside of the `awk` script with `awk -F","`.

You can could store the header as a variable when `NR==1`. Store the file numbers in an array and write the header only once if the number is NOT in the array yet. Once the value is in the array, you will just write the lines to their respective file as you set it up before:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==1{header=$0}NR>1&&!a[$2]++{print header > ("file"$2".csv")}NR>1{print > ("file"$2".csv")}' fullfile.csv
```

Output:

file1.csv

```
animal,number
rabbit,1
mouse,1
dog,1
```

file2.csv

```
animal,number
fish,2
lizard,2
cat,2
```

Comment: can you please explain the 'NR==1{header=$0}NR>1&&!a[$2]++  part of the script??

Comment: @Pooja25 Sure. `NR==1{header=$0}` says that if we are on the first line store the entire line under the variable `header`. The next expression tests that we have moved passed the header with `NR>1` and also uses an `awk` array trick with `!a[$2]++` -- this construction tests if `$2` is _not_ in the array yet and if it is not it adds it. So the first time we encounter a new value in `$2`, say `1`, we start a new file called `file1.csv` beginning with the header. We store `1` in the array so the header for `file1.csv` will only be written out once.

Comment: thank you very much. I really appreciate it. One more question, why do we need to use ("file"$2".csv")}NR>1{print > ("file"$2".csv")} twice? I mean what does the second print > ("file"$2".csv") do?

Comment: The file name  ("file"$2".csv") , $2 value is coming in double quotes on file name which i dont want. Now the file name is like: ABC."123".csv, I want ABC.123.csv. Would you please help ?

Comment: I got it. My data in the file is double quoted , so the quotes were coming on the file name, I have used awk -F "\",\"" and the problem got solved.

Comment: @Pooja25 The reason we use the print statement twice is that the first time we are printing the header, which only happens when `NR>1&&!a[$2]++`. The next print is to print the actual data, which only requires that `NR>1`. Usually only one print happens but if a new value in column 2 is encountered we are creating a new file so we need the header and hence the two print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler awk command with better formatting.

```
awk -F, '
NR==1 {hdr=$0; next}
{fn="file" $2 ".csv"}
!seen[$2]++{print hdr > fn}
{print > fn}' fullfile.csv
```

Sample output

```
$ for i in file*.csv; do echo $i; cat $i; echo; done
file1.csv
animal,number
rabbit,1
mouse,1
dog,1

file2.csv
animal,number
fish,2
lizard,2
cat,2
```